# Need an element in an object of array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, antd

I have an array with elements like,

```
let arr = [
  {id:1, name:'ty',flag:0},
  {id:2, name:'bg',flag:1},
]
```

I'm using antd Select (dropdown) this array is used to print options like

```
<Select size="small" dropdownMatchSelectWidth={false} placeholder="Select..." onChange={() => {}}>
  {MasterData && MasterData.FinClass && MasterData.FinClass.map((d) => <Select.Option value={d.FC}>{d.FC}</Select.Option>)}
  {arr.map((d) => <Select.Option value={d.id}>{d.name}</Select.Option>)}
</Select>
```

On onchange I want the corresponding  flag also. How will it get ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the selected id and the array element this way.

```
<Select
  size="small"
  dropdownMatchSelectWidth={false}
  placeholder="Select..."
  onChange={(value) => {
    console.log(arr.filter((a) => a.id === value)[0]);
  }}
>
  {arr.map((data, i) => (
    <Select.Option key={data.id} value={data.id}>
      {data.name}
    </Select.Option>
  ))}
</Select>
```

Live demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-dew-s76m8q?file=/index.js:316-665

Answer (score 0):

### Use Second Param of onChange

**Method 1**

You can get the flag value from the second parameter of onChange

```
const handleChange1 = (value, option) => {
  console.log(option); // {key: "2", value: 2, children: "Two", flag: 2}
};
```

```
const options1 = [
    { id: "1", name: "One", flag: 1 },
    { id: "2", name: "Two", flag: 2 },
    { id: "3", name: "Three", flag: 3 }
];
```

But you need to pass flag as a prop to `<Select.Option>` as below

```
<Select
   placeholder="Method 1"
   style={{ width: 120 }}
   onChange={handleChange1}
>
   {options1.map((data) => (
      <Select.Option key={data.id} value={data.name} flag={data.flag}>
         {data.name}
      </Select.Option>
     ))}
</Select>
```

There is a better way of doing this.

Antd Select now supports `options` prop. Instead of mapping your options as done above, you can simply pass it as a prop with minor changes to your options array as below

**Method 2**

```
const options2 = [
  { key: "1", value: "One", flag: 1 },
  { key: "2", value: "Two", flag: 2 },
  { key: "3", value: "Three", flag: 3 }
];
```

```
<Select
  placeholder="Method 2"
  style={{ width: 120 }}
  onChange={handleChange2}
  options={options2}
/>
```

You exactly get what you pass as an `option` in the handle change which has the required `flag` property.

```
const handleChange2 = (value, option) => {
  console.log(option); // {key: 1, value: "One", flag: 1}
};
```

> In method 2 ff options data is not in the required format ( key, and value are required ),
> You can reformat the existing data using a helper function.

[LIVE CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/sof-74979320-r5dmws?file=/demo.js)